# Are OpenType font features supported in any iOS web browsers through CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, opentype

The current version of desktop Chrome supports OpenType features through CSS.

1) My testing shows that neither Safari nor Chrome on iOS 5 support OpenType features. Is that right? (I know I hav the right `-webkit-font-feature-settings` CSS tags, because the OpenType features work fine in desktop Chrome.)

2) Is the situation different on iOS 6?

Answer (score 1):

It seems iOS supports OpenType font features only partially [according to this page](http://caniuse.com/font-feature), but I don’t know to what extent these features are supported, as the page I linked doesn’t elaborate on that and I don’t own any iOS device.